# How do I save software on a 3DS transfer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

So I've recently bought a New 3DS XL to replace my old 2DS, and the 3DS has a copy of Super Mario World pre-installed on it. When I do a system transfer, is there any way to save the game??

Comment: Is the New 3DS XL that you purchased the Lime Green one? Because if so, when you do the system transfer, it should keep the game.

Answer (score 2):

After posting my speculative comment, I did a little bit of research and found [this article](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14143/~/information-about-pre-installed-games-on-nintendo-3ds-family-systems) by Nintendo about the pre-installed software for the 3DS.

> Pre-installed games are stored on the SDHC Card or microSDHC Card included with the system. This means that a portion of the available space will be taken up by the pre-installed game. If you choose to delete the content off the SDHC Card or microSDHC card, **such as during a system transfer**, the pre-installed game **will be available for redownload from the target system's Nintendo eShop** after the transfer has been completed.

(Emphasis mine.)